# Perl CGI using span to style data

Tags: perl, cgi, html

I'm a CGI/HTML/CSS newbie but not too bad with perl.  I'm writing a little CGI script and need to know how to change the style for certain elements of data on a line of text. I have adopted the Object Oriented approach to using CGI.

I'm iterating through an array of data and want to change the style of the variables on each line to something different from that standard style. My output for each line will look something like:

```
server=$hostName  appHost=$appHost  port=$port   cache=$maxCache
```

At the moment, I'm just doing:

```
print $cgi->br("server=$hostName  appHost=$appHost  port=$port   cache=$maxCache");
```

I'd ideally like each of the variables to be say, bold red (or preferably, a style that I've created in my CCS style sheet). I'm thinking that perhaps I need to use the span element but i've tried and failed miserably
Many thanks & regards
John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your perl script, write:

```
print $cgi-br "server=<span class='myclass'>$hostName</span>  appHost=<span class='myclass'>$appHost</span>  port=<span class='myclass'>$port</span>   cache=<span class='myclass'>$maxCache</span><br><br>";
```

(notice that the `<br><br>` needs to be inside the string, not outside).

Then in your CSS file, put:

```
.myclass {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

You link them together by having your perl script print the following in the `<head>` section of the HTML:

```
print $cgi-br "<link rel='stylesheet' href='URL of your CSS file'/>";
```

Comment: Wow!  That was quick!  I will try this out after a cup of tea and let you know how I get on. Many thanks for taking time out to answer this Barmar.  Regards